# Может ли AppCode полностью заменить Xcode для iOS Intern/Junior разработчика?

Tags: xcode, ide, мобильная-разработка, jetbrains, инструменты-разработчика

Я хочу стать iOS-разработчиком. Но есть одна проблема: у меня ноутбук Dell, под управлением Windows 10, а Xcode доступен только на macOS. Из качественных альтернатив Xcode я выбрал JetBrains AppCode. У меня вопрос: **До тех пор, пока я буду на позиции Intern или Junior (пока не заработаю на macOS), могу ли я использовать только AppCode?** Где-то слышал мнение, что без Xcode разрабатывать не получится, а AppCode используют как дополнение к Xcode. Так ли это? Смогу ли я создать качественное (боле-менее простое) iOS-приложение, используя только AppCode на Windows 10? А так же смогу ли я его запустить в AppCode?

Comment: Проблема не в IDE, проблема в том, что без операционной системы Apple у вас в принципе ничего не получится сделать кроме ввода текста без особых перспектив как-то его запустить и проверить. Поэтому либо развернуть ОС с помощью Hackintosh или виртуальной машины на вашем железе, либо купить продукцию Apple. Ну а тут все просто, раз у вас есть ОС - значит у вас есть и возможность работать с XCode.

Comment: @AlexKrass, а каким образом правильно создать виртуальную машину? И будет ли она корректно работать при 4Гб ОЗУ?

Comment: Ну из своего опыта я ставил из любопытства по гайду из интернета "VMWare установка MacOS". Для виртуальной машины вы отдаете только часть оперативной памяти. Но даже если оперативной памяти будет достаточно, не могу сказать как он себя поведет на ноутбуке в зависит от железа.

Comment: @AlexKrass, понял. Спасибо!